# How to connect logstash to logstash?

Tags: logstash, devops, elastic-stack

I'm trying to parse the Nginx `access.log` log with `logstash` and try to send `logstash`, but I haven't found any example.

Is there anyone who can help me solving this problem?

Comment: Could you please include what have you tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. i want to learn whether such a thing is possible.

Comment: Here's a [configuration example from the Official logstash documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-config-for-filebeat-modules.html#parsing-nginx) for nginx access logs.